# What is the maximum value of work done by this force field?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, optimization, line-integrals

An object moves in the force field $F=yz\hat{i}+zx\hat{j}+xy\hat{k}$ starting at the origin and ending at some point $A(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ that lies on the surface $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}+\dfrac{z^2}{c^2}=1$. What is the maximum possible value of the work done $W = \displaystyle\oint F \cdot dr$?

There are several ways that I've tried, and all are a little problematic, so far:

Since the curve that the object is moving along starts at $(0,0,0)$ and ends at $A$, this is not a closed curve, so we can't apply Stokes' theorem.

I computed the curl of $F$ and got $(0,0,0)$, so $F$ is a gradient field.  And it's easy to see the corresponding potential function:  $f(x,y,z)= xyz$.

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Line Integrals, which is specifically for gradient fields, tells us that the integration will be path-independent.

However, I don't know how to parameterize this curve.

Also, should I use the integrand $f(\gamma(t))(\gamma'(t))dt$, assuming I have a parametrization for the curve, or should I use the "exact differential" as my integrand, $f_xdx + f_ydy + f_zdz$?

Thanks,

Comment: You don't have a closed curve, but since the field is conservative the FTC for line integrals tells you the work depends only on the end point.  To solve, you need a formula for the work integral expressed in terms of $\xi, \eta, \zeta$.  Then we maximize the function over the ellipse using Lagrange multipliers, for example.

It seems like integration along a straight line path from the origin to the ellipsoid would be doable.

Comment: See JimmyK's answer...

Comment: Hi @Titus, yes, JimmyK gives a great answer indeed - although I am just wondering whether the wording of the question is problematic?  We are maximizing subject to the constraint g = 1, g is the ellipsoid.  But we are not told that the object even moves along the ellipsoid - it just ends up there.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the force field $F(x,y,z) = yz\hat{i}+zx\hat{j}+xy\hat{k}$ is a conservative force field with a potential function of $f(x,y,z) = xyz$. Hence, the work done in moving from the origin $O(0,0,0)$ to a point $A(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ is simply $f(\xi,\eta,\zeta) - f(0,0,0) = \xi\eta\zeta$.

Since the point $A(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ is on the surface of the ellipsoid $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}+\dfrac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$, we must have $\dfrac{\xi^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{\eta^2}{b^2}+\dfrac{\zeta^2}{c^2} = 1$.

So, you simply need to maximize $\xi\eta\zeta$ subject to the constraint $\dfrac{\xi^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{\eta^2}{b^2}+\dfrac{\zeta^2}{c^2} = 1$.

This is a simple problem which can be solved by Lagrange Multipliers. Note: If all of the Greek letters are confusing, you can simply maximize $xyz$ subject to $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}+\dfrac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$.

Comment: Hi @JimmyK4542, this is a silly question but, why maximize subject to the constraint, call it g =1, which is the level curve of the ellipsoid?  We only know that the object *ends up* on the ellipsoid, and that it started from the origin.  What if the object was moving along a curve that wasn't on the ellipsoid during the entire time and just landed on the ellipsoid at the final time?  Then we should compute its work done on some curve *not* on the ellipsoid.  Of course, I am certain that the problem's intent matches your idea but do you think there's a problem in the wording of the question?

Comment: Since the force field is conservative, the work done by the force on the object only depends on the starting and ending points, not on the curve itself. Obviously, the curve doesn't lie solely on the ellipsoid, since it starts at the origin, but the end point $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ is on the ellipsoid, which is how we got our constraint.

Comment: Ahh...awesome comment @JimmyK4542 :-)

Comment: Thanks so much, @JimmyK4542!